# Should I move from Java programming to Delphi programming?

Tags: java, delphi

over the years i have been employed in a permanent position with firms that did their development work in Windows SDK, VC++, and most recently Java; in my own eyes, I am language independent.

Should I move from Java to Delphi (assuming pay-scale remains unchanged)?

I'm concerned because, for the most part, the net presents a relatively bleak picture for this particular skill.

Comment: Should you?  I find this site very informative on questions of this type:  http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~ssanty/cgi-bin/eightball.cgi

Comment: Why the closure vote? It's a genuine question, and perhaps one the answer to which may be referred back to in the future. The fact that it is subjective does not in any way make it argumentative

Comment: There is no "correct" answer to your question. What is right for *you* depends upon a myriad of factors not in your question. What is right for everyone else is not answerable question. From the FAQ: "Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!"

Comment: According to the Magic Eight Ball: Absolutely! :-)

Comment: @Craig: Agreed, that's what the subjective tag is for.

Comment: Delphi is a very nice language (and safe). C people would die to have some of its features (cool strings, range checking, great debugger, great IDE, F U L L support for cross platform - write code once compile everywhere). However, it is true that jobs are rare today.

Comment: I think the best advice for anyone with this type of question is: try it out and see how you like it!

Answer (score 4):

The [TIOBE Index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) is an often cited source for estimating the popularity of programming languages. Java, C and C++ have been the top 3 for a very long time. As you can see, Delphi is a lot lower on the list (at position 10 at this moment). (Ofcourse you should not take the TIOBE Index as an absolute measure, but it does indicate something).

This can be an advantage as well as a disadvantage. There are probably a lot more Java and C++ jobs than there are Delphi jobs, but there are also a lot more Java and C++ programmers than Delphi programmers, so it's harder to stand out as a Java or C++ programmer among the masses. Having a specialism that not many people have, such as for example Delphi, may help you get a higher salary, though you'll have to search harder to find Delphi jobs.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what your goals are, but I believe that for regular apps the future bears name "GWT", i.e. Java. (I consider Delphi a history for quite a while, but that's JMO.)

Comment: I see you are from Prague. There were recently really nice job offers with GWT, +1 here

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely worth learning Delphi. A lot of software's still being written in it,  stuff which people use and rely on.  A lot of companies prefer to keep quiet about it, though, since it presents such a major competitive advantage over other, more popular languages.

For example, you ever work with VOIP on chat programs?  In my experience, there are two basic categories:  Skype, and The Other Stuff.  Skype "just works", while the others tend to be very glitchy and unreliable.  And it's no coincidence that Skype's written in Delphi while (AFAIK) none of the other chat programs are.  That's just one example among many.

Comment: How does Delphi make Skype any more reliable than other VOIP programs?  That argument doesn't even begin to make sense.  Furthermore I believe you're saying that the Skype client is written in Delphi, which doesn't say anything about reliability.  You'd have to look at Skype's backend and what their servers are running.

And for the record, if I had a nickel for every time Skype dropped a call, I'd be rich.

Comment: @Jonescb: Yes, I'm talking about the client.  The way it never seems to have trouble detecting my microphone, doesn't make you jump through all sorts of hoops to set it up for voice chat, and just generally does what it's supposed to do and stays out of your way.  This requires some very complicated code, and Delphi helps the authors get it right because, as Jerry Coffin noted, it's *better thought out* than other languages.

Comment: @Jonescb: The servers are a completely different matter, of course, though I guess you've had a different experience than I have.  Only time I ever have a "dropped call," on Skype or any other IM for that matter, is when the other person's router craps out on them.  (A depressingly common occurrence for some of my friends.)

Comment: @Mason: Skype likes to steal sound only for itself, making computer completely quiet+deaf when I quit Skype. Happens quite regularly. I don't think you are making any favor to Delphi when judging it by Skype.

Comment: Really? I've never had that happen.  What plug-ins are you using?

Comment: None. (Unless Skype has some in its default installation.)

Comment: What a horrible and biased answer. Why is this upvoted? People are using Delphi and not telling anyone because it gives them a competitive advantage? That doesn't even make sense and is a ridiculous claim without any evidence provided for it either. And you chose Skype because it is about the only highly used program made in Delphi, without any evidence whatsoever that the call quality had to do with the language used. Additionally, in this day and age, Skype is *far* from the best VOIP program and I've changed apps because of it's poor quality.

Answer (score 2):

It never hurts to pick up another skill, but I haven't seen any Delphi job listings anywhere.  I suspect you would be better suited picking up a new language/framework/platform with more "legs", such as WPF, JavaFX, Objective-C/Cocoa, ActionScript/Flex, or something of the like.

Answer (score 2):

As a technical move, it's probably a good one -- Delphi is better thought out and more enjoyable to use. From a career perspective, however, you're probably right -- Delphi has been rather marginalized for some time now, and doesn't *seem* to be in the process of making a huge comeback.

Comment: I'd say that "enjoyableness" is quite subjective...

Comment: http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html
Delphi appears to be slowly climbing.

Comment: @Malcolm: It's a bit like saying Cameron Diaz is prettier than Roseann Barr. Theoretically it's subjective, but in reality it's hard to imagine more than a *minuscule* percentage of people disagreeing (unless they just don't know what's being discussed).

Comment: Not sure where you've been in the last two years, but Delphi's been making quite the coneback lately now that it's out from under the incompetent management that dragged it down.  I've seen a lot of "how do I do <this Java thing> or <this C# thing> in Delphi?" questions on here, especially in recent months.

Comment: @codeelegance:yes, Delphi seems to be climbing a bit, and Java does seem to be falling a bit -- but unless the *rates* change significantly, Java's going to remain more widely used than Delphi for quite a while.

Comment: @Mason: As noted in my reply to @codeelegance, yes, it's making *something* of a comeback, but not a *huge* comeback. Tiobe puts it at ~2.4% share, rising at .2% annually, where Java is at ~18%, dropping ~2% annually. *If* those rates remained unchanged, it'll be a long time before Delphi catches up with Java. Of course, they probably *will* change long before that, but I don't think there's any reasonable way to guess what's going to happen 5 or 10 years from now.

Comment: If you meant "enjoyable" more like "painful", then yes :)

Comment: @Xorty: If you're one of those people who lust after Roseann Barr, so be it (see previous comments).

Comment: Cameron Diaz is nearly 40 years :) For me, it's too out-dated (just like delphi :D). I don't know what was the last version of Java that you used, but now it's more like Jessica Alba 8-)

Comment: @Xorty:Currently using Java 6, update 20. If the comparison has to be to somebody younger than Roseann, perhaps Amy Winehouse, but definitely not even close to Jessica Alba.

Comment: Well have you ever thought why so many people prefer Java over Delphi? It's not use who are have weird tastes, it's you :)

Comment: Well, I don't know about "minuscule percentage of people disagreeing", I don't have any statistics on this subject. But as Xorty said, Java programmers are definitely much more required than Delphi ones. If Delphi is so enjoyable, why is it used more rarely than Java?

Comment: @Malcolm:It's largely a matter of mismanagement of Borland. Despite its technical superiority, for 10 years (or so) I would have recommended against depending on it because its vendor seemed intent on self destruction.

Comment: So... What exactly prevents from using Delphi?

Comment: @Malcolm: mostly lack of momentum. It's nicer than many alternatives, but not *enough* nicer to convince a lot of people to drop what they're doing and switch to it.

Comment: How do you feel about the Delphi comeback three years later? :P

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba: Honestly, surprised (and disappointed) but how little change there's been to either Delphi or Java. Java updates have been too few and too small, so it's losing ground constantly. Worse, although ugly, it at least used to at least be secure and dependable but that silver lining seems to be mostly gone as well. Only Android has saved Java from massive losses of market share. Embarcadaro has done some good things both technically and in how the market the product, but apparently not (nearly) enough in either to sustain any kind of major comeback.

Answer (score 2):

I was using Delphi before I swtiched to C++ and then to Java. I don't think that moving from Java to Delphi is wise idea. Why so?

- Java is widely used
- It's easier to find Java job
- More years of Java -> Better chance getting senior position job (java oriented)
- Java is definitelly richer as for libraries
- Java rocks in enterprise sphere, Delphi doesn't
- It's easier to find resources for Java - from tutorials for beginners to manuals for professionals
- Java runs on other operating systems by default, remember? (I know Lazarus, but can't compare port to nativeness)
- From my exprience, more experienced programmers and software engineers kind of condemn Delphi programmers ...
- Java is suitable for larger projects (means bigger money)

The only good reason for preferring Delphi over Java I can actually think of is making Windows GUI application. But since we have .NET and wonderful WPF, Delphi doesn't score even here.

You make your choice, but personally, I'd never switch back to Delphi (ok maybe if payment was too good to reject:))

Comment: wonderful WPF...? cough, cough

Comment: 'From my exprience, more experienced programmers and software engineers kind of condemn Delphi programmers ... '
why do they condem delphi programers?????? please explain

Comment: I am not sure, I am just saying facts. Maybe the think that Delphi is more like for beginners or what ...

Comment: Many many big empty statements there like "Java is suitable for larger projects". How would you backup that? Obviously you never learned Delphi only tangentially scratched it. Prove me wrong!

Comment: "The only good reason for preferring Delphi over Java I can actually think of is making Windows GUI application" - As I said. Probably this is how YOU used Delphi.

Comment: "Java runs on other operating systems" - So do Delphi. Have you updated your Delphi knowledge recently? Delphi apps runs natively on Linux, iOS, osX, windows, android.

Comment: Java rocks in enterprise sphere, Delphi doesn't - what kind of rocks are we talking here about? Because NO matter what project you do in Java, can do it also in Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

The way you phrase your question makes me think you've got a job offer already for a Delphi developer position. If the language is the only thing stopping you, I say you should go for it.

It will add experience with another language to your resume besides being fun (learning something new). Just make sure you keep your skills in Java and C++ reasonably up to date when or if you need to move on.

Answer (score 1):

Why limit yourself to one language?

A major problem with Delphi is that some people consider it an "easy" language. So there are Delphi programmers that can drag some controls to a form without any real coding knowledge. So if you are a good developer and skilled in Delphi, you won't have that much trouble finding a job.